# MS SQL ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE decryption with PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, encryption

I need to decrypt a string encrypted with MS SQL ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE with PHP or MySQL.

I already tried using mcrypt in various ways which just returns strings like '���h� �¯��������|�niIW�q;ɵJ��i��� ��7�'. Also tried different block-modes like "ecb", "cbc", "cfb", "ofb", "nofb" or "stream".

I also tried using DES_DECRYPT in MySQL which just returns the same as the input.

The PHP function i tried:

```
public function Decrypt($data, $secret){

            //Generate a key from a hash
            $key = md5(utf8_encode($secret), true);

            //Take first 8 bytes of $key and append them to the end of $key.
            $key .= substr($key, 0, 8);

            $data = base64_decode($data);

            $data = mcrypt_decrypt('tripledes', $key, $data, 'ecb');

            $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('tripledes', 'ecb');
            $len = strlen($data);
            $pad = ord($data[$len-1]);

            return substr($data, 0, strlen($data) - $pad);
        }
```

The MySQL i tried:

```
SELECT DES_DECRYPT( 'string', 'key:mykey' ) AS decrypt
```

I hope you can help me find a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the original passphrase used to encrypt this key?

Comment: Yes i have the original passphrase.

Comment: So why are you trying to generate a key, use the one used to encrypt this data originally

Comment: @RiggsFolly Don't confuse key and passphrase. Keys have a very specific length in bytes, but passphrases can have arbitrary lengths. That's why he is trying to derive a key from the passphrase with MD5. The problem is that the TSQL documentation doesn't disclose how the derivation procedure works (which hash is used? how are things encoded?).